# When will CMP be part of OpenSSL?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, openssl, x.509

CMP means Certificate Management Protocol.
CMP for OpenSSL is currently a fork of OpenSSL. Do you know when it will be part of OpenSSL?

https://github.com/mpeylo/cmpossl

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to ask. Why not simply contact the author of this fork on what the plans are?

Answer (score 3):

It will be part of OpenSSL 3.0. The code is currently being contributed in chunks. Chunks 1-6 have already been merged into the OpenSSL master branch (which will eventually become OpenSSL 3.0). Chunk 7 is being reviewed right now:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/10620

There are 12 chunks planned:

https://github.com/mpeylo/cmpossl/wiki

OpenSSL 3.0 is scheduled for release at the end of this year. The release schedule is here (scroll down about 2/3 of the page):

https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html